# Export Server certificate To use in XAMPP for SSL

Tags: ssl, ssl-certificate, windows-server-2019

I had to upgrade to XAMPP 8.2.4 on our new OFFLINE web server when we replaced our OFFLINE web server. Both servers are Windows Server 2019. Our old OFFLINE web server was running 8.0.0. In 8.1.0 php uses secure channels and we need to setup SSL. I have a CA setup on my Offline network and have a CA issued certificate on the new server. I need to setup certificate (.crt and .key) file to direct to with XAMPP so I can get our new web server working. How do I export my server cert to the correct format for XAMPP so I can configure SSL. I can export the cert without the key as a .cer but if I export it with the key it exports as a .pfx. Pretty sure XAMPP can't use those for the SSL. Does anyone know how to do this? We can't really use online tools to do this. Or would it better to make a self-signed on the server itself and export that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So not sure why this worked but he issue here was that I had to make a C:\openlap\ folder which I didn't have on the previous version of XAMPP but it is referring there for the certificate. Not sure where in XAMPP it calls this out but I would like to move it from that location. But it is working now.